# AppEngine data strategy to handle a large index per user?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, database-design, google-cloud-datastore

I’m building an AppEngine app in Python.

For the sake of discussion, imagine I’m building a Gmail clone. Except with a million short emails per user.

The point is, each user will have a large search index, all to theirself; just like Gmail, each user has a personal “search engine” of their own content.

Now imagine that many of these messages belong to multiple users (e.g. mailing list emails or cc:ing a hundred users).  Not all, but some reasonable fraction.

Without prematurely optimizing, what is my best bet to store the data and the indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about storing a list of User keys in each mail message?  That's assuming that a single message won't be owned by more than a hundred or so users.

```
class User(db.Model):
    "usual properties like name, etc"

class Message(db.Model):

    # list of users that have this message
    users = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

If you want an unlimited number of user * message relationships, you could use another table:

```
class UserMessage(db.Model):

    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
    message = db.ReferenceProperty(Message)
```

here's a couple of good articles on modeling relationships like these on GAE:

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html
http://blog.notdot.net/2010/10/Modeling-relationships-in-App-Engine

Answer (score 0):

```
class User(db.Model):
    pass

class Message(db.Model):
    text = db.StringProperty()

class MessageIndex(db.Model): # parent is a Message
    users = db.StringListProperty() #users keys

class UserIndex(db.Model): # parent is an User
    messages = db.StringListProperty() #messages keys
```

Take a look [here](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html) or read the [pdf](http://www.scribd.com/doc/16952419/Building-scalable-complex-apps-on-App-Engine).